# How to make Linux System work via Oracle VM Box on a Apple MacBook M1 running MacOS Big Sur?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, macos-big-sur, apple-m1, kernel-extension

I want to use Linux on my M1 MacBook for my Info Sec course. I have installed the latest version of Oracle VirtualBox (6.1.26). It installed just fine with no glitches. But after importing the .ova file, when I start the system. It gives two error boxes.

[VM Box Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH4g8.png)
[VM Box Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrjJa.jpg)

I have tried a bunch of fixes. [Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) Getting Errors in macOS Big Sur 11.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149373/kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908-getting-errors-in-macos-big-sur-11-0-1)

[Unable to start a Linux VM in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/1361401/unable-to-start-a-linux-vm-in-virtualbox-with-a-kernel-driver-not-installed-rc)

But this doesn't work. First of all, I didn't get any message in the System preferences > Security & Privacy > General section. Secondly, when i run the commands mentioned in the link above, it says

> *Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e.
> Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e*

[Terminal Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWgO9.jpg)

I guess this is a M1 specific problem because of the arm64 architecture.
Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Could you use [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Virtual Box you try to import was installed with an x86_64 archtiecture. As of now it is not possible to run a x86-based guest on an M1 Mac since they are different architectures.

EDIT:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#hostossupport

Lists all supported HOST os. It requires Intel Macs as for now.
Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]